# groupby count, sum, subset based on condition of the other column's values (count and make new row based on condition)

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I started to learn pandas in 30 days ago. I only knows basics of pandas.

I have a data frame as shown below.

Which is sorted based on ID and date

```
    ID  Status  Date    Cost    Duration
0   1   F   2017-06-22  500     nan
1   1   M   2017-07-22  100     30.00
2   1   P   2017-10-22  100     92.00
3   1   F   2018-06-22  600     243.00
4   1   P   2018-08-22  150     61.00
5   1   F   2018-10-22  120     61.00
6   1   F   2019-03-22  750     151.00
7   2   M   2017-06-29  200     nan
8   2   F   2017-09-29  600     92.00
9   2   F   2018-01-29  500     122.00
10  2   M   2018-03-29  100     59.00
11  2   P   2018-08-29  100     153.00
12  2   M   2018-10-29  100     61.00
13  2   F   2018-12-29  500     61.00
```

from the above dataframe, I would like to prepare below dataframe as below.

Expected out:

```
   ID   ID_F  PS  No_of_F   No_of_M   No_of_P    NoD_to_PS    PS_to_F
   1    1_F1  nan   0         0         0          nan          nan
   1    1_F2  P     1         1         1          122          243
   1    1_F3  P     2         1         2          426          61
   1    1_F4  F     3         1         2          487          151
   2    2_F1  M     0         1         0          nan          92
   2    2_F2  F     1         1         0          92           122
   2    2_F3  M     2         3         1          487          61
```

In the above expected dataframe there are 4 entries for ID=1, because ID=1
has 4 F's.

PS = Previous Status to that F

No_of_F = Number of F before that F

No_of_M = Number of M before that F

No_of_P = Number of P before that F

No_of_days_to_PS = Number of days to PS from the starting

PS_to_F = Number of days from PS to that F

Comment: I think you have one bad row in your desired output.  Can you check the fourth value of `No_of_days_to_PS`?

Comment: @user3483203 My bad, I am sorry, edited. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To easily vectorize this, you can calculate based on the *entire* frame, and then index down to only `F` values, which results in your desired output.

---

```
g = df['ID']

dg = df['Date'].groupby(g)

dm = dg.shift() - dg.transform('first')
mdm = dm.mask(dm.eq(pd.Timedelta('0D')))

d = dict(
  PS=df['Status'].shift(),
  No_of_F=df['Status'].eq('F').groupby(g).cumsum().sub(1),
  No_of_M=df['Status'].eq('M').groupby(g).cumsum(),
  No_of_P=df['Status'].eq('P').groupby(g).cumsum(),
  No_of_days_to_PS=mdm,
  PS_to_F=df.Date.diff(),
)

pd.DataFrame(d)[df['Status'].eq('F')]
```

```
     PS  No_of_F  No_of_M  No_of_P No_of_days_to_PS  PS_to_F
0   NaN      0.0      0.0      0.0              NaT      NaT
3     P      1.0      1.0      1.0         122 days 243 days
5     P      2.0      1.0      2.0         426 days  61 days
6     F      3.0      1.0      2.0         487 days 151 days
8     M      0.0      1.0      0.0              NaT  92 days
9     F      1.0      1.0      0.0          92 days 122 days
13    M      2.0      3.0      1.0         487 days  61 days
```

Comment: Is it possible to have ID column respectively.

Comment: Edited the expected out put, It is very helpful if we have ID column mentioned above